# How do I know which user is Administrator in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, settings, administrator

I want to check logged-in user is Administrator or not in a Python file?

How can I guess Administrator is it User's ID, Name Or Setting Access Rights?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [self.env.is_admin()](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/api.py#L594) to check if a given user has group `Access Rights`, or is in superuser mode

***Function definition:***

```
class Environment(Mapping):
    
    def is_admin(self):
        """ Return whether the current user has group "Access Rights", or is in
            superuser mode. """
        return self.su or self.user._is_admin()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you can get the ID of the Administrator user by using this code:

admin_id = self.env.ref('base.partner_admin')

For the access rights, you can check if the administrator user is already in a specific security group by using this Python code:

self.env.ref('base.partner_admin').has_group('module_name.group_id')

Answer (score 0):

try this...
i think it will hepls you...

```
from odoo import SUPERUSER_ID
```

and print this SUPERUSER_ID in your .py file, it return id of super user...

and fire query on res_users table...

```
select * from res_users where id = SUPERUSER_ID;
```

Comment: You don't need a SQL query to check this.

Comment: yes, you can direct use SUPERUSER_ID without fire this query,
you can direct search in users table with orm search method and it will return recordset of superuser...